# Initialization of char array in a struct

Tags: c, data-structures

I was writing a structure from a book, and then see how it does initialization.
I don't get it, how he does that.

```
struct node
{
 char target[50];
 char stack[50];
 char *s,*t;
 int top;
}
```

Initialization function:

```
void init
{
 p->top = -1;
 strcpy(p->target,"");
 strcpy(p->stack,"");
 p-t = p->target;
 p->s="";
}
```

So I want know how he is using `strcpy` to initialize an array or char.

Comment: It's not very clear what your question is, and the init function isn't even syntactically correct.

Comment: he used strcpy thats  why i include c++

Comment: There should be a semicolon after the struct definition.

Comment: What book? As if it's a C book, we'll probably want to avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He is **not** doing it. The statement `strcpy(p->target,"");` does **not** initialize the 50 positions of the array. It just puts a 0 in the first position. (See this [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcpy/).)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the example in this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcpy/